# Should I leave off extra curriculars completely in my resume?

Tags: interviewing, resume, job-search, fresher

I'm applying for tutorial jobs. I'm sort of a fresh graduate. I finished my undergraduate in 2014 and then my graduate studies just this year. During my graduate studies I tutored part-time.

In the resume template given by my university, I suggested the following order: job objective, education, extra curriculars, work-related experience and then about me. Thinking more, I think the template was for university students applying for internships or fresh graduates without work experience.

So far during the interviews I have had, **no tutorial center asked about my extra curriculars**. They are more interested in my tutoring experience. I think the extra curriculars are taking up space in my resume. I never did much extra curriculars in undergraduate studies anyway. Those are just there for show so no one thinks I didn't do any extra curriculars in undergraduate studies, which is practically the case.

I was considering moving work-related experience ahead of extra curriculars, but am now considering removing them completely.

**Am I probably better off without them, or should I just move up work-related experience?**

In case this gets too opinion-based, please advise to me some guidelines as to the how relevant is extra curriculars.

Of course, I can just leave this off my resume 2-3 years from now, but for right now while I am a sort of fresh graduate, how important is it for tutorial centers to know that I have had some extra curriculars in college even though the interviews so far have been mostly about my tutorial experience?

Comment: Listing hobbies could help you if they're unusual and appropriate. I, for example, was a commercial pilot in a previous career. I listed "flight instruction" as a hobby. I just happened to have a former Army pilot as an interviewer. During the "cool down" at the end of the interview we talked about flying. It turned out we knew a lot of the same people. Had I left off my hobbies I never would have made that personal connection. Now, something like "I enjoy killing and stuffing chipmunks for religious reasons" is probably a fact you should keep to yourself.

Comment: Things don't seem to add up here: you say you didn't too much extra-curricular, but you are also worried about it taking too much space?

Answer (score 3):

Short answer: If it's not relevant to the job for which you are applying, leave it off your resume, as it is just clutter.

Longer answer:

First off, anything extracurricular should be at the **end** of your resume, not the beginning.  In fact, your resume should be in this order:  Skills summary (if technical), and special certifications, Work experience, additional experience, and education last.  The further you get from school, the less they are going to care about your education, unless it's ongoing education or certifications.

Also, as I stated above, if it's not relevant to the job, it's just filler.  If your resume is less than a page, then by all means include it near the end under "additional experience" but try to keep it relevant to the job.  If you're not being asked about it on interviews, that's a good hint that it is not relevant.

With younger candidates such as yourself, hiring managers are a bit more forgiving, but learn good habits now, because your grace period comes with an expiration date.

Answer (score 0):

If you have room then I would include it.  For sure don't go to a second page for extra curriculars. I agree put it last. I feel like even work experience prior to college is more important as it is still work experience.  I was on the some club sports teams it came up on some interviews.

Answer (score -1):

keep in mind recruiters' time and volume of resumes they have to sift through. if it is not value added to your application, I would leave it out.

Comment: Don't forget they are also looking for people who pass the airport test - having nothing outside of work /university wont help you with that